# What is the flow of Liferay for blocking and transactional cache?

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-6

I'm coding a Spring aspect in order to intercept methods annotated with `@Transactional` to replicate the behavior of Liferay.

So, in my aspect the code looks like:

```
@Aspect
class TransactionAspect extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter
{
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionAspect.class);

@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional *)")
public void beanAnnotatedWithTransactional() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {}

@Pointcut("within(foo.bar.services..*)")
public void beanInsidePackage(){}

@Before("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithTransactional() && beanInsidePackage()")
public void publicMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithTransactional()
{
    if ( TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isNewTransaction() )
    {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);
        TransactionalPortalCacheHelper.begin();
    }
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(int status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case STATUS_COMMITTED :
          TransactionalPortalCacheHelper.commit();
            logger.info( "Commit!" ); break;

        case STATUS_ROLLED_BACK :
            TransactionalPortalCacheHelper.rollback();
            logger.info( "Rollback!" ); break;

        case STATUS_UNKNOWN :
            logger.info( "Upps!" ); break; //TODO throw runtime exception?
    }
}
```

}

Using this code, the methods are intercepted as expected. However the result of call to getCount of an entity, add one element, and counting again is not correct.

This is normal if we see the code from Liferay:

```
try {
        session = openSession();            
        BatchSessionUtil.update(session, foo, merge);
        foo.setNew(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw processException(e);
    } finally {
        closeSession(session);
    }

    finderCache.clearCache(FINDER_CLASS_NAME_LIST_WITH_PAGINATION);
```

Here is clearing the cache after commit, but at the end, this call to clearCache arrives to:
@Override
    public void removeAll() {

```
    if (_log.isTraceEnabled()) {
        _log.trace(getAbbreviatedCacheName() +  " DEL ALL");
    }

    if (TransactionalPortalCacheHelper.isEnabled()) {
        TransactionalPortalCacheHelper.removeAll(_portalCache);
    }
    else {
        _portalCache.removeAll();
    }
}
```

And `TransactionalPortalCacheHelper`what say to that call?

```
protected static void removeAll(PortalCache portalCache) {
    Map<PortalCache, Map<Serializable, Object>> portalCacheMap =
        _peekPortalCacheMap();

    Map<Serializable, Object> uncommittedMap = portalCacheMap.get(
        portalCache);

    if (uncommittedMap != null) {
        uncommittedMap.clear();
    }
}
```

The problem here is, what happens with data on portalCache? Is not cleared! Because TransactionalPortalCacheHelper is enabled.

But, the question is: if I test this behavior using Liferay method interceptor, it works as expected and I have always correct results. But if I use the aspect that I already coded, the problem described appears. So, what is the real flow of Liferay with elements been added and counted and the state of portalCaches contained into FinderCache?